# how to stop jquery change css of all the divs onhover of a single div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, onhover

I have blocks of information displayed in divs. I want to change the css of a particular div on hover. But currently when I hover over anyone div the css for all the divs change.

Here's my jquery code :-

```
<script>
        $('.student-box').hover( function(){
            $('.student-info').css('opacity', '0.8');
            $('.student-info').css('margin-top', '-20px');
            $('.student-info').css('height', '130%');
            $('.onhover-ul').show();
        },
        function(){
            $('.student-info').css('opacity', '0.7');
            $('.student-info').css('margin-top', '75px');
            $('.student-info').css('height', '63%');
            $('.onhover-ul').hide();
        });
    </script>
```

How do I change the jquery so that only the div which is hovered upon is affected. There can be a lot of student which means lot of "student-box" will be generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.student-box').hover( function(){
    var div = $(this);

    div.find('.student-info').css({
         opacity: '0.8'
         marginTop: '-20px',
         height: '130%'
    });
    div.find('.onhover-ul').show();
}, function(){
    var div = $(this);

    div.find('.student-info').css({
        opacity: '0.7',
        marginTop: '75px',
        height: '63%'
    });
    div.find('.onhover-ul').hide();
});
```

It doesn't matter that you called the `hover()` method on a div, inside the callback you're still just saying 'select all elements with the class ...'

Inside the callback function, `this` is the DOM element that actually triggered the event. So you can wrap this in jQuery and call methods on it.

Using the `css()` method in this way though isn't advised, you're better off adding a class name and moving the styling to a style sheet, otherwise you've got presentation in your behaviour.

Comment: I do have those classes in my stylesheet-and i have other properties for them.  But to create the hover effect I guess I'll need to use jquery, rite?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.student-box').hover( function(){       
       // $(this) is DOM element what hovered at this moment

       $(this).find('.student-info').css({
          'opacity': '0.8',
          'margin-top', '-20px',
          'height', '130%'
       });
   },
   function(){
         // unhover code like hover
   })
);
```

Comment: but student-box and student-info are two different classes

Comment: Actualy `$(this)` is a jQuery object containing the DOM element that was hovered. `this` is the DOM element